# Postgres using b-tree only partially - why?

Tags: sql, postgresql

The index:

`CREATE INDEX message_index ON message(queue_id, target_client_id, timestamp ASC, source_client_id);`

The query:

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE  SELECT content FROM message WHERE message.queue_id = 5 AND message.source_client_id = 5 AND (message.target_client_id = -1 OR message.target_client_id = 5) ORDER BY timestamp ASC LIMIT 1;`

Output:

```
 Sort  (cost=8.39..8.39 rows=1 width=13) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=0 loops=1)
   Sort Key: "timestamp"
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
   ->  Index Scan using message_index on message  (cost=0.27..8.38 rows=1 width=13) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=0 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((queue_id = 5) AND (source_client_id = 5))
         Filter: ((target_client_id = (-1)) OR (target_client_id = 5))
 Total runtime: 0.034 ms
```

Why does postgres perform a quicksort in the beginning, why does it not make use of the timestamp attribute from the index? And what does (...rows=1) mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sort is done at the **end**, not at the beginning.

You have to read the execution plan from starting with the inner most node which is `Index Scan using message_index on message` and then "go up the tree".

So the order of execution is

1. Retrieve the rows from the index
2. Sort the retrieved rows using the `timestamp` column (which btw is a horrible name for a column)

The `rows=1` in the first pair of parentheses means that Postgres *expected* (estimated) this step to return only a single row. The `row=0` in the second part means that in reality no rows where returned based on the `where` criteria.

The individual parts of the output are explained in the manual:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html

You also might want to read through the information from this site:
http://use-the-index-luke.com/

Comment: By the way. Is my assumption correct that the quick sort only is there in case the estimated row count is wrong? I.e. more than one row is returned by the index scan?

Answer (score 0):

It cannot use the index to provide the ordering because `target_client_id` precedes `timestamp` in the index definition, and `target_client_id` is not specified in the where clause with equality to a single value.

In theory an index like that could be used to provide ordering by doing two index scans, one for each specified value of `target_client_id`, to fetch rows in order for each one.  It would then do a merge of the two ordered streams.  But PostgreSQL was not written to do that type of optimization.  (And in this case, it would probably not actually be an optimization.)

Yes, the sort is there in case it returns more than 1 row.